# Invalid scope Swagger and IdentityServer4

Tags: swagger, identityserver4, swagger-ui

I keep getting Invalid Scope error in IdentityServer4 after I Authorize through swaggerui

I tried using these configurations

```
new Client
{
    ClientId = "swaggerui",
            ClientName = "Swagger UI",
            AllowedGrantTypes = GrantTypes.Implicit,
            AllowAccessTokensViaBrowser = true,

            RedirectUris = {"http://localhost:5001/swagger/oauth2-redirect.html"},
            PostLogoutRedirectUris = {"http://localhost:5001/swagger/"},

            AllowedScopes =
                    {
                            "webapi"
                    }
},
```

and the following configuration on the swaggerui

```
c.AddSecurityDefinition("oauth2", new OAuth2Scheme
{
    Type = "oauth2",
            Flow = "implicit",
            AuthorizationUrl = "http://localhost:5000/connect/authorize",
            TokenUrl = "http://localhost:5000/connect/token",
            Scopes = new Dictionary<string, string>
    {
        {
            "webapi", "My API"
        }
    }
});
```

IdentityServer recognizes the client, but doesn't seem to get the webapi scope.I keep getting Invalid scope.
What am I missing?

Comment: How did you configure IdentityServer in your C# application?  Did you register those custom scopes with IdentityServer's resource store? You can use the 'AddInMemoryApiResources' extension method after the 'AddIdentityServer' if you haven't

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to make sure `webapi` is a valid API resource scope. Most likely you haven't configured this API resource yet. Add the below to wherever your API resource configuration information is stored on the Identity Server 4 side.

```
new ApiResource("webapi", "My API");
```

Comment: Yes that was it... Thanks you